# How to create an array of the variations of n elements in sets of k peaces?

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax, combinations

I have the elements `0` and `1`. I want to get an array of their possible variations, with each variation having a length of `k`, where `k = 2^(2^n) (n = 0, 1, 2, ...)`. Currently, I do this:

```
case k
  when 2  then ['0', '1']
  when 4  then [0, 1].product([0, 1]).map(&:join)
  when 16 then [0, 1].product([0, 1]).product([0, 1]).map(&:flatten).product([0, 1]).map(&:flatten).map(&:join)
end
```

but this is not elegant. What would be a good solution which would take `k`? Mine only works for `2^1`, `2^2`, and `2^4`.

Comment: Your current code shows permutations not combinations. You should update your question to clarify your intent.

Comment: You are mixing up `0` and `1` with `"0"` and `"1"`. Which?

Comment: @Sawa - my initial elements are integeers, but at the end I want to have strings. All three examples produce strings at the end.

Comment: @AlexPopov You didn't write that in the question. Also, combination implies that it should not be a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just binary representation of integers from 0 to N-1...

```
irb(main):008:0> 16.times.map {|x| "%04b" % x }
=> ["0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"]
irb(main):009:0> 4.times.map {|x| "%02b" % x }
=> ["00", "01", "10", "11"]
irb(main):010:0> 2.times.map {|x| "%01b" % x }
=> ["0", "1"]
```

In general for 2<sup>n</sup>:

```
irb(main):014:0> n=3; (1<<n).times.map {|x| "%0*b" % [n, x] }
=> ["000", "001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"]
```

---

If you truly want the *k* combination of *n* elements, which is an entirely different concept what the question illustrates, [Ruby already have that method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
irb(main):023:0> [1,2,3,4].combination(2).to_a
=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Nice! This is *elegant*!

Comment: `"%0*b"` - Here what does `*` and `b` mean?

Comment: Those are permutations, not combinations. Also, the OP is asking for `2^(2^n)`, not `2^n`.

Comment: @sawa: That's what OP's code product. These are not permutations either.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: `*`: Use next argument as field width, `b`: Format as binary digits.

Comment: @KennyTM The OP's code represents permutations, or not? Which? I wrote yours are permutations.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: You may check http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf for the syntax of format string. It is similar to C's printf.

Comment: @Linuxios New thing for me.. I still not understanding how that code works.. Would you help me?

Comment: @KennyTM Just saw your tags summary http://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm?tab=tags and noticed that Ruby isn't even listed on the first page! How long have you been using Ruby?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Some questions like this only require a little specific knowledge and some googling.

Comment: @sawa: This is a Cartesian product as in [0, 1]⁴. Permutation of n elements will give a array of length `n!` (`[123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]`).

Comment: @KennyTM You are right. It would be better expressed as Cartesian product.

Comment: @KennyTM Now it looks great.

Comment: Guys, first thank you all for the help and sorry for the confusion. I always mix the three concepts (combination / permutation / variation). I always check [this link](http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/PermVarComb.html) as a reference. So in my case I am asking - how many sets can you have, consisting of four slots, being able to choose from two elements for each slot. I think this is `n^k`, where `n` is the number of elements (in my case 2) and `k` is the number of slots (in my case 2, 4, 8 etc.). So after all this is probably neither combination, nor permutation, but variation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can take at most two elements from `[0, 1]`, the combinations for taking more than two from it will be zero. Therefore,

```
case k
when 2 then [[0, 1]]
else []
end
```

Answer (score 1):

KennyTM's answer is fine. The result is a permutation with repetition. Array does have a method for that, if more flexibility is needed.

```
[0,1].repeated_permutation(4).map(&:join)
#=> ["0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"]
```